# Read TCP socket using Azure

Tags: azure

I'm looking for a way to read from an external TCP socket using Azure and store push the data to an Event Hub. I can't really find a fitting service for this on Azure, other than a Docker container or a VM with custom code.

Anyone has a suggestion?

Comment: Webjob or Azure Function or Azure Container Instance or - why not - a Worker Role in Cloud Services. They all have pros and cons.

Comment: Do they all have the possibility to connect to and read from a remote tcp socket?